# Restoring NSTableView sort order after reload

Tags: objective-c, nstableview

In Interface Builder, an NSTableView is set up with sortable columns (by clicking on the column headers).  The data source uses an NSArray.  When updating a row of data, the table's data is reloaded which refreshes the array and lays out the data rows according to the array's order.

I would like to keep the table column's sort order.  I tried saving the table's sortDescriptors, reloading data, and restoring the table's sortDescriptors, but that does not trigger the desired reload.  I suspect I want to refresh the array according to the sortDescriptors such that reloading will lay out as desired.  Please enlighten me.

Comment: Use `NSArrayController`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was under my nose.  I can use the data source method `tableView:sortDescriptorsDidChange:`.

I think a cleaner solution is to post the notification for the data source.  It should be the same notification as when clicking on a column header.  If anyone knows, kindly share here.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using `NSArray` use `NSMutableArray` in datasource and sort according to the sortDescriptors.Mutable array will keep the records as per your table columns sort order.